# Try-Catch functionality behind the scenes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, try-catch

Imagine a block of code like this where I ask for the comments not displayed yet below a post (there could be a button to load more comments).

```
try {
  const postId = post._id;
  const res = await axios.get(
    `${baseUrl}/api/posts/moreComments/${postId}`,
    {
      params: { yetDisplayedLength },
    }
  );

  const newComments = res.data.comments;

  setComments((comments) => [...comments, ...newComments]);

  setCommentsLength(res.data.commentsLength);
} catch (error) {
  alert(error + "\n Error loading more comments");
}
```

My question is: if there is an error in receiving the comments, the try is immediately aborted or it continued and then the comments are set anyway (`setComments((comments) => [...comments, ...newComments]);`) ?
I ask this because in the catch block I don't know if I have to set the comments state like it was previously (`setComments((comments) => comments.pop())`)

Comment: Code execution stops as soon as there is an error and jumps to the `catch` block. If `axios.get()` fails, you won't get `newComments` assigned, for example, nor `setComments` would run, nor `setCommentsLength`. Logically, there is no way for those to run, even - how do you get comments out of nothing? The `axios.get` didn't even return a `null` or anything, just errored.

Comment: I tought axios.get could handle to return a null or something like that, but in the last line of your comment you clarify it. Thanks VLAZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: if there is an error in receiving the comments, the try is immediately aborted or it continued...

Control is transferred from the `try` block to the `catch` block **immediately** when the error occurs, not later. See [MDN's writeup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

You can also try it:

```js
function fail() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 100, new Error("failed"));
    });
}

async function example() {
    try {
        console.log("A");
        await fail();
        console.log("B");
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error:", e.message);
    }
}

example();
```

Note that you only see `A` logged before the error, not `A` and `B`.